# Prove if lambda is an eigenvalue of a matrix A, then lambda + 1 is an eigenvalue of A + I.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Any advice on solving this question, I realize that in this case Ax = lambda(x) and that the determinant of the identity matrix is equal to 1. I don't know where to go from here though. I initially thought I could just replace A with lambda and take the determinant of I, but I don't feel like that works.

Took another attempt at it, is this correct?:
A + I = lambda + 1
[substitute lambda for A]
lambda + I = lambda + 1
[subtract lambda from both sides]
I = 1
[substitute 1 for I into the original equation]
A + 1 = lambda + 1
A = lambda

Comment: Start with writing the definition of something being an eigenvalues.

Comment: I somehow feel that this question has been here before on MSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose $v $ is eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $λ$, then, $Av=λv$, now take the same $v$ and apply $ A+I $ we have $(A+I)v=Av+v=λv+v=(λ+1)v $ so we found λ+1 is eigenvalue of the linear transformation $A+I$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

There exists $\;0\neq v\in V\;$ s.t. $\;Av=\lambda v\;$ , and thus

$$(A+I)v=Av+v=\ldots$$